# BATCH FILE : not able to display variable value by accessing by %variable%

Tags: batch-file

I am using widows XP OS and have batch file where I set few variable values.
when i echo those varibales i can see the values, but when i use it in some commands i get empty sting as its value.

Sample Batch file

```
@ECHO OFF 
          SET "output=select * from employee where empid='160'"
          CALL SET output=%%output:'=''%%
          ECHO "%output%"
sqlcmd -b -h-1 -m-1 -V1 -S testsvr  -E  -Q "%output%' " -d tesdb
```

o/p select * from employee where empid=''160''

and value of variable in sqlcmd command is empty space.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, what you want to do.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET output=select * from employee where empid="160"
ECHO %output%
ECHO sqlcmd -b -h-1 -m-1 -V1 -S testsvr  -E  -Q '%output%' -d tesdb
```

..output is:

```
select * from employee where empid="160"
sqlcmd -b -h-1 -m-1 -V1 -S testsvr  -E  -Q 'select * from employee where empid="160"' -d tesdb
```

Comment: i am trying to execute sqlcmd , but during execution that %output% value was coming null , then i echo it and there too same problem

Comment: You did remove the last `echo`?

Comment: If `empid="160"` has double quotes, it's not the reason for the issue. "sometimes it goes, sometimes not" need a new hard disc??

Comment: nothing as such, any idea when variable values get lost , during run , unles we explicitely set it to set var =

Answer (score 1):

Try to place the quotes as follows:

```
SET output="select * from employee where empid='160'"
sqlcmd -b -h-1 -m-1 -V1 -S testsvr  -E  -Q %output% -d tesdb
```

Comment: things are working fine , but its sometime coming and some time not may be related to env variable , do i need to reset it

Comment: If it works fine sometimes then it is likely that the dataset or characters being echo'd are the problem.  Batch has poison characters.  Open a cmd prompt and type your batch file name - you will see any error messages then.